# How to make a correct call to GetModuleFileName with UnicodeStrings

Tags: winapi, c++builder-10.3-rio

GetModuleFileName is not returning the program file name of a Windows service.

I have already defined the variables as AnsiString and UnicodeString, but it seems that there is something related to the event handler I am using to get this value in.

```
AnsiString exefile = "", sIniFile = "", AppFile = "";

DWORD tamanho = MAX_PATH;
LPTSTR lpBuffer = exefile.c_str();

this->LogMessage("Iniciando serviço",EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,0,0);

tamanho = GetModuleFileName( NULL, lpBuffer, tamanho );
if( tamanho > 0 ){ // retornou nome !
   exefile = String(lpBuffer);
}
else
{
     this->LogMessage("Impossível determinar pasta do  executável",EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE,0,0);
     Started = false;
     return;
 }

 sIniFile = ChangeFileExt( exefile, L".ini");
 if( !FileExists(sIniFile) )
 {
    this->LogMessage("Arquivo de inicialização não   encontrado",EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE,0,0);
    Started = false;
    return;
 }
 else
      this->LogMessage(sIniFile,EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,0,0);
 /*
 // Debug
 Started = true;
 return;
 */
```

There is not any error messages. The application successfully compiles, it does not find the initialization file which actually exists in the application path though.

I have used the same code on another service application and it works perfectly.

What am I doing wrong please?

Is there any tutorial showing examples of dealing with UnicodeStrings?

Comment: Have you checked if GetModuleFileName returns the correct string? And after ChangeFileExt?

Comment: You don't appear to have allocated any memory into which the string can be read. And you pass a buffer that you claim is `MAX_PATH` long, but in fact it is empty. If you want to use a fixed length buffer, declare a fixed length array of `wchar_t` and pass that.

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamew), especially the part about the return value. *If the buffer is too small to hold the module name, the string is truncated to nSize characters including the terminating null character, **the function returns nSize, and the function sets the last error to ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER**.* You're not checking for failure by just checking for a return value > 0.

Comment: @Anders 3, Yes, I have checked. This code works fine when I run it on other Windows services. I have tried to log a message concatenating a String and the value of "exefile" just after the return of GetModuleFileName and I have got a String having two application path values concatenated, just like it happens when someting is wrong.

Comment: @David Heffernan, As you can see at the location wher the link to Documentation which Ken White have offered, the size parameter must be sufficient for hold the return of the function, otherwise it will be truncated. The size parameter has notting in common with the initial size of the buffer.

Comment: I am afraid it is just related to the way I am dealing with Unicode Strings

Comment: You are wrong. You tell the function that there is room to store MAX_PATH characters. But no buffer is allocated at all. Anyway, use a fixed length character array.

Comment: You're wrong. The size tells Windows what size buffer you have **preallocated** to receive the content, which you did not do in your code above. (You essentially fed false information to the API, as you said you allocated `MAX_PATH` for the buffer when you did no such thing.) You need to read that documentation again, especially the part I quoted (and **bolded** for emphasis) in my previous comment. And *successfully compiled* means nothing other than that you've met syntax requirements; it doesn't mean you've properly called the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You are misusing `GetModuleFileName()`.

You are not passing an *allocated* buffer to `GetModuleFileName()`, so it has nowhere to store its output.  A string's `c_str()` method never returns a NULL pointer, so if the string is empty, `c_str()` returns a pointer to a null character that is stored in static memory.  You are telling `GetModuleFileName()` that you have allocated memory for the buffer you give it, but you really haven't, so when `GetModuleFileName()` tries to write to your non-allocated buffer, it will either trash memory, or outright just crash.

Use something more like this instead:

```cpp
this->LogMessage(_D("Iniciando serviço"), EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, 0, 0);

WCHAR szBuffer[MAX_PATH];
DWORD tamanho = GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, szBuffer, MAX_PATH);

if( tamanho == 0 ){ // retornou nome !
{
    this->LogMessage(_D("Impossível determinar pasta do  executável"), EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE, 0, 0);
    Started = false;
    return;
}

String exefile(szBuffer, tamanho);

String sIniFile = ChangeFileExt(exefile, _D(".ini"));
if (!FileExists(sIniFile))
{
    this->LogMessage(_D("Arquivo de inicialização não encontrado"), EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE, 0, 0);
    Started = false;
    return;
}

this->LogMessage(sIniFile, EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, 0, 0);

/*
// Debug
Started = true;
return;
*/
```

Or, you can do this:

```cpp
this->LogMessage(_D("Iniciando serviço"), EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, 0, 0);

UnicodeString exefile;
exefile.SetLength(MAX_PATH);

DWORD tamanho = GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, &exefile[1], MAX_PATH);

if( tamanho == 0 ){ // retornou nome !
{
    this->LogMessage(_D("Impossível determinar pasta do  executável"), EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE, 0, 0);
    Started = false;
    return;
}

exefile.SetLength(tamanho);

String sIniFile = ChangeFileExt(exefile, _D(".ini"));
if (!FileExists(sIniFile))
{
    this->LogMessage(_D("Arquivo de inicialização não encontrado"), EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE, 0, 0);
    Started = false;
    return;
}

this->LogMessage(sIniFile, EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, 0, 0);

/*
// Debug
Started = true;
return;
*/
```

That being said, you don't actually need to call `GetModuleFileName()` directly at all.  You can use the RTL's [`ParamStr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ParamStr) <sup>1</sup> function instead.  When its `Index` parameter is 0, it returns the path and filename of the calling process (ie, it calls `GetModuleFileName()` internally for you), eg:

```cpp
this->LogMessage(_D("Iniciando serviço"), EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, 0, 0);

String exefile = ParamStr(0);

String sIniFile = ChangeFileExt(exefile, _D(".ini"));
if (!FileExists(sIniFile))
{
    this->LogMessage(_D("Arquivo de inicialização não encontrado"), EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE, 0, 0);
    Started = false;
    return;
}

this->LogMessage(sIniFile, EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, 0, 0);

/*
// Debug
Started = true;
return;
*/
```

<sup>1: In a VCL Forms Application, the `Application->ExeName` property simply returns `ParamStr(0)`.</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much @Remy Lebeau for answering my question. By the way what _D( String ) does ?

Comment: In C++Builder 2009, `System::Char` changed from `char` to `wchar_t`, and `System::String` changed from `AnsiString` to `UnicodeString`. `UnicodeString` is UTF-16 on all platforms, but it uses `wchar_t` only on Windows, it uses `char16_t` on other platforms. `_D()` is the RTL's equivalent to Microsoft's `TEXT()` in the Win32 API. `_D()` maps the input char/string literal to match `System::Char`. It is better to use `_D("literal")` instead of `L"literal"` if you need to code for non-Windows platforms, or want to be forward-compatible should `System::Char` ever change type again in the future.